# Cannot target a class from HTML that's loaded into another html by Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, include

Has anyone tried html jquery load file? How can I possibly use Jquery to control a class from a Html that's loaded from Jquery? A direct content of my header html will work if inserted into index.html. However I'm trying to use the Jquery include file as there will be a lot of pages so a separate file is much more feasible. The problem is when I target a certain class or id in js it won't do anything.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="slides">  
  <ul class="slides-container">
    <li>
      <img src="img/site_images/bg_home01.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="caption">
      <div class="title_pre">Development</div>
      <h1>The City Below<br>The life above</h1>
      <p><a><i class="icon-play"></i>Play Video</a></p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/foundation.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.superslides.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">        </script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script> 
$(function(){
$("#header").load("header.html"); 
});
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

header.html

```
<header>
    <a href="#" class="pull">Menu</a>
    <div class="navlogo">
       <a href=""><img src="http://placehold.it/150x40"></a>      
    </div>
</header>
```

app.js

```
$(document).foundation();
$(".navlogo").fadeOut();
```

Comment: Problem can be, that you first load app.js and after that header.html. Try place `<script src="js/app.js"></script>` in footer and make the loading of content of app.js on document.ready.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix with a different approach.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="import" id="template-file" href="header.html">
<body>
    <script>
    var getImport  = document.querySelector('#template-file');
    var getContent = getImport.import.querySelector('#header');
      document.body.appendChild(document.importNode(getContent, true));
    </script>
<div id="slides">  
  <ul class="slides-container">
    <li>
      <img src="img/site_images/bg_home01.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="caption">
      <div class="title_pre">Development</div>
      <h1>The City Below<br>The life above</h1>
      <p><a><i class="icon-play"></i>Play Video</a></p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

header.html

```
<header id="header">
<a href="#" class="pull">Menu</a>
<div class="navlogo">
   <a href=""><img src="http://placehold.it/150x40"></a>      
</div>
</header>
```

app.js

```
$(document).foundation();
$(".navlogo").fadeOut();
```